# What is the difference in View and EER Diagram?

Tags: mysql, eer-model

I quite confuse with both. First, both might seen the same. May I know how the View and EER Diagram is apply?

Comment: Differences between them = Apples v/s oranges.
Applied to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View is a stored query** accessible as a virtual table composed of the result set of a query. View is the perspective on the data from tables. It actually does not store data in it but give you the access like tables from the database only thing is you may not allow to insert data in to it.

**EER/ER is nothing but data modelling techniques** of the database. It is not acting on data but on the structure of tables in database. Generally it gives snapshot of tables & their relation. This is helpful to get the idea that howz the data flows in a database.